# Get bytes count using iptables when having a Docker host

Tags: iptables, docker

When I want to count the number of bytes getting out a Linux system through a particular port I can use iptables, adding a specific rule that can be checked whenever I need.

For instance lets imagine that I need to know how many bytes go out through port 22. I can add the following rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22
```

And when I need to know the answer to my question, I run:

```
iptables -L -nvx
```

Or if I need just the bytes:

```
iptables -L -nvx | grep :22 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

My problem is that if that system is running Docker, the iptables are changed as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/) and I can't get the desired effect (if I repeat the process above I always get 0 bytes even knowing that was traffic on that port).

Can someone please explain how can I obtain the same bytes count in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In default Docker setups, the container gets its own network namespace, which is completely separate from the host system.

Therefore your container has a separate iptables instance.

If you want to access host networking namespace, you need to make it available to the container. I don't have enough experience to know if you can have both host network namespace and container network namespace in use at the same time.

Bringing host network namespace inside container breaks security features that containerisation brings.

Comment: I don't need to create an iptables rule inside a docker container!
I just want to add a rule in a system that has docker host running, and because of that the iptables were changed to a level that the procedure I used to follow don't work anymore.